# Best approach to do deployment using Jenkins on production servers

Tags: git, jenkins, ssh

I want to do the production deployment using Jenkins and looking for a secure and compliance acceptable approach.

**A little background**

- I want to create a simple Jenkins job using a shell executable that will fetch the latest code, replace some files and then restart the services.
- My production server is accessible only via the Jump server.

**Current Approach**

- I am thinking to add the production server as an agent in my Jenkins to save ourself from the complexity of login to Jump server and then ssh to the production server
- We have three such production servers where we need to do the deployment and with the above case, will have to add all three servers to Jenkins.

*Is it the right option or we should go with Jump server as an agent and then ssh to different machines??*

If we go with the other approach i.e. Jump server as an agent then would it be feasible to run commands such as git pull/fetch, service start-stop, etc as an argument to the ssh command?
The current script that I have for this approach looks something like this-

```
ssh username@production-server bash -c "'

sudo systemctl stop nginx
cd /home/username/code
git fetch --all
git checkout "$branch_name"
sudo cp /home/username/code/index.html /usr/share/doc/HTML/index.html
sudo systemctl start nginx

'"
```

Also, there would be some if-else statements later on in this script.

So to summarize my question-

Is it okay to add production servers directly in Jenkins as agents (Jenkins is accessible only by privileged people) and run this kind of command/script or to add Jump server as an agent and then run commands/script as an argument over ssh?

Other best approaches/suggestions are most welcome!

Answer (score 1):

> add the production server as an agent in my Jenkins to save ourself from the complexity of login to Jump server and then ssh to the production server

That would never fly in the find of institution I am working with: SSH is *always* blocked, except through a jump server.

Any deployment is actually done by [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), which does have SSH connection authorization to prod servers. Jenkins is there to trigger a `tower-cli`, to launch the Ansible job.